# Variable selection using regsubset in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a Tweets Project and I extracted 87 variables, now i need to perform variable selection method so i used forward subset selection. But i'm facing an error.

```
 regfit.fwd = regsubsets(screen_name ~.,merge_tweets,method = "forward",
                    complete.cases(merge_tweets),nvmax = 15)

  Error in leaps.setup(x[, ii[reorder], drop = FALSE], y, wt, 
  force.in[reorder],  : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)

  > head(merge_tweets)
  X    user_id    status_id created_at    screen_name
  1 1 1339835893 1.090257e+18 1548772454 HillaryClinton
  2 2 1339835893 1.090002e+18 1548711688 HillaryClinton
  3 3 1339835893 1.089999e+18 1548710912 HillaryClinton
  4 4 1339835893 1.089994e+18 1548709837 HillaryClinton
  5 5 1339835893 1.089994e+18 1548709756 HillaryClinton
  6 6 1339835893 1.089994e+18 1548709738 HillaryClinton

 text
 1                                                                       On 
top of human suffering and lasting damage to our national parks, the Trump 
shutdown cost the economy $11 billion. End shutdowns as a political hostage- 
taking tactic. 
2    Hurricane Maria decimated trees and ecosystems in Puerto Rico. Para La 
Naturaleza's nurseries have made a CGI commitment to plant 750,000 trees in 
seven years. The team here has already grown 120,000 seedlings and planted 
30,000 trees.               source display_text_width is_quote is_retweet favorite_count 
retweet_count lang
1 Twitter Web Client                192    FALSE      FALSE          14324          
4168   en
2 Twitter Web Client                235    FALSE      FALSE          10684          
2526   en
3 Twitter Web Client                238    FALSE      FALSE          11423          
2089   en
4 Twitter Web Client                 34    FALSE      FALSE           1293           
113   en
5 Twitter Web Client                222    FALSE      FALSE           6641           
951   en
6 Twitter Web Client                214    FALSE      FALSE          12192          
2108   en
                                                 status_url            name     
location
 Hillary 
Clinton New York, NY
 Hillary 
Clinton New York, NY

description
1 2016 Democratic Nominee, SecState, Senator, hair icon. Mom, Wife, Grandma 
x2, lawyer, advocate, fan of walks in the woods & standing up for our 
democracy.
2 2016 Democratic Nominee, SecState, Senator, hair icon. Mom, Wife, Grandma 
x2, lawyer, advocate, fan of walks in the woods & standing up for our 
democracy.
                  url protected followers_count friends_count listed_count 
statuses_count
1    FALSE        24017203           784        
41782          10667
2      FALSE        24017203           784        
41782          10667
3      FALSE        24017203           784        
41782          10667
favourites_count account_created_at verified             profile_url      
profile_expanded_url
1             1138         1365530675     TRUE 
2             1138         1365530675     TRUE 
3             1138         1365530675     TRUE
```

I have removed some url columns as it doesn't support url to be posted. It would be great if anyone can  help me out in solving this problem.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: are you allowed to share your data? if so can you edit your question and add the output of  `dput(merge_tweets)` ?

Comment: I have made the changes as per your request.